# I'm trying to program something from an exercise in my Java Book, not quite getting what is being asked of me

Tags: java, arraylist, bluej

Its talking about Generic Classes and saying how you can create classes of generic types that aren't String, or Integer, or Double from ArrayList where you import the ArrayList.

The book clearly states you can write fields such as this:

private ArrayList members;
private ArrayList  machines;

and then you can make Classes based off this in the constructor and assign them.

Exercise 4.4 says to make a private field of "library" that can hold an ArrayList of type "Book".

Exercise 4.5 asks for a local variable of cs101 that can hold an ArrayList of Student.

Then by 4.7 it wants asssignments to the library, cs101, and track variables, to create the appropriate ArrayList objects.

Here is what I wrote (not including some of the methods) adding it into an already available project within the BlueJ projects folders.

import java.util.ArrayList;

```
/**
 * A class to hold details of audio files.
 * 
 * @author David J. Barnes and Michael Kölling
 * @version 2011.07.31
 */
public class MusicOrganizer
{
    // An ArrayList for storing the file names of music files.
    private ArrayList<String> files;
    private ArrayList<Book> library;
    private ArrayList<MusicTracks> tracks;
/**
 * Create a MusicOrganizer
 */
    public MusicOrganizer()
    {
         ArrayList<Student> cs101;
        files = new ArrayList<String>();
        library = new ArrayList<Book>();
        cs101 = new ArrayList<Student>();
    }
```

It tells me that it can't find the symbols for Book and MusicTracks, but I've defined them exactly the way the book defines private ArrayList members; and private ArraryList machines; so i'm confused as to how the symbols can't be found as it can't even find the symbols that are defined in my school book either, which leads me to believe that maybe its my computer?

What do you guys think?

Comment: This means your compiler can't find the `Book` and `MusicTracks` classes. You've either forgotten to import them, or you're expected to write them as part of the exercise.

Comment: Really eh? I thought something wasn't right there at all. thanks so much everyone for the clarifications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're telling the program that you want an Arraylist of Book objects called "Library" and an arraylist of Student objects called cs101. Now you have to create those objects/classes. You don't have to make a string class because java already has a String class that is there for you.

Book class:

```
    public class Book{
         private String name, genre, author;
         //This is called a constructor that instantiates Book objects
        public Book(String name, String genre, String author){
          //now you build the book object by assigning THIS particular book object with the passed in values
           this.name = name;
           this.genre = genre;
           this.author = author;
    }
}
```

Now you would have to do the same for Student. You would also want to use access/mutator methods most likely (getters and setters).

Comment: thank you. That was my mistake I had to create the classes. I knew it was something simple. I'm so bad for that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a class called "Book" and a class called "Student" for that code to be correct. The ArrayList class is defined as ArrayList , E being a placeholder for any type of object.

When you create an arraylist like this

```
ArrayList<Book> = new ArrayList<>();
```

You're saying you want to create an array list that can hold Book objects. If there is no Class called Book, Java will not know what you want. Create 2 simple classes, something like

```
public class Book{

   private String name;

   public Book(String n){
      this.name = n;
   }
//getters and setters after
}
```

And a student class

```
public class Student{

   private String name;

   public Student(String n){
      this.name = n;
   }
//getters and setters after
}
```

Add those to your project and now your ArrayList declarations are valid as you have a class for Book and a class for Student.